# discarding milliseconds from the average time calculated

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

Here is my code:

```
SELECT cluster_id, AVG(min_per_imei_cluster::TIME) as avg_time 
FROM arrival
group by cluster_id
```

The avg_time column gives values with milliseconds and beyond. How do I truncate or round to the nearest second?

I tried using

```
AVG(min_per_imei_cluster::TIME)::timestamp(0)
```

but got the following error:

```
SQL Error [42846]: ERROR: cannot cast type interval to timestamp without time zone
```

Comment: What is the data type of `min_per_imei_cluster`? Does it stand for a point in time or a duration?

Comment: it is a point in time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can use the [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) function to specify the level of precision that you want. So in this instance, you would do date_trunc('second',min_per_imei_cluster).